# Does anybody know how to sniff in promiscuous mode on OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, networking, wireshark

I often need to sniff traffic on my home wireless network for troubleshooting purposes.  My network is unencrypted/in-the-clear.

I used to be able to do this on my Macbook Pro -- and I can't any more.  "used to" == years ago, on another Macbook Pro -- and on an older version of OS X and Wireshark.  Now it seems impossible to do on the latest version of Wireshark, and OS X 10.8.4.  I recall having to setup a script on terminal to "tweak the permissions" of some files / drivers....but I can't seem to find that script anymore -- nor can I find any help online.

Anyone here able to do this?

regards,
JBP

Answer (score 1):

> I recall having to setup a script on terminal to "tweak the permissions" of some files / drivers

That's probably referring to the permissions on the `/dev/bpf*` devices.  That's not something necessary to sniff in promiscuous mode, it's something necessary to sniff *at all* unless you're running as root.

Recent versions of Wireshark, going back at least to Wireshark 1.8.0, install a script to do that automatically.  Open up a Terminal window and do `ls -l /dev/bpf*`; it should report the `/dev/bpf*` devices, e.g. `/dev/bpf0`, `/dev/bpf1`, etc. as having permissions `rw-rw----` and as being owned by `root` and group `access_bpf`.  In addition, the `id` command should report you as being a member of group `access_bpf`.

If that's all the case, Wireshark should show an `en0` device and possibly an `en1` device.  Older MacBook Pros will have both, with `en1` being your AirPort (wireless) adapter; the Retina MacBook Pros don't have a build-in Ethernet, and `en0` will be your AirPort adapter.

When you start up the latest version of Wireshark (1.10.0), what does it show you in the "Capture" section of the main window?  Does it show any interfaces?  If so, does it show one as "Wi-Fi", e.g. "Wi-Fi: en0" (which is what displays on my Retina MacBook Pro, running 10.8.3 - BTW, 10.8.4 is Mountain Lion, not Lion) or "Wi-Fi: en1"?

If it does, try clicking on "Capture Options".  It should pop up a dialog with a list of interfaces at the top, including the one labeled as "Wi-Fi".  Double-click that interface; it should pop up a dialog letting you edit the interface options.  You could turn on promiscuous mode, but you might need monitor mode.  Try promiscuous mode first; if that doesn't work, try monitor mode.